# Software Raid vs Fake Raid on Intel RSTe

Tags: raid, software-raid, fakeraid

I'm using Intel RSTe - a fake raid.
Intel suggests mdraid (which is software raid utility).
Intel does not like dmraid (which is a fake raid utility).
(Correct me if I'm wrong)

Intel says it augmented mdraid to support metadata from RSTe.

Now my question is do I need to setup the Raid in the RSTe bios utility, or put the disks in AHCI and then setup the raid in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally suggest to set drives as AHCI and use only linux mdadm.

The reason is that if you move your drives to whatever other server, you just use the same mdadm utility and you don't have to care wheras there were some "compatible" metadata before or not.

Comment: Another reason to go this way is that mdadm is quite a bit more flexible than the BIOS when managing the array. Also, GRUB manages the boot loaders there with ease. Otherwise you might need to create a small array (100MB per disk is what I usually do), create the big array, then dismantle the small array and install the boot loader(s) there. :) I have a boot loader on every RAID 1 member disk.